# Something like ExtAspNet controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, web-controls, asp.net-webcontrol

Recently I discovered [ExtAspNet Controls](http://extaspnet.codeplex.com/)  and I am so cheerful with it.
Only disadvantage for me is that no documentation and mostly support and descriptions are written on Chinese language. Before I go on and dig it into my projects Ill love to know is there something similar with English support and more documentation and samples.

Main features that I like at ExtAspNet is

1. Free for use
2. Ajax and simple for use
3. Most of needed controls are covered as Grids, Datepicker, Tabs, Panels all in one place
4. ASP.NET and C# as native and primary platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ExtAspNet similar controls from this website, www.ext.net. Their controls are both open source for open source projects and commercial licenses.